# email content sent by sendGrid is hidden

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, html-email, sendgrid

I try to send email with node.js by using sendGrid but the email sent always being hidden as shown:

[image]

nodejs code:

```
 const msg = {
     to: 'example@gmail.com',
     from: 'example@example.app',
     subject: 'example: quotation email',
     text: msgText,
     html: "<style>.tab {padding-left: 18xp;}</style>" + msgText ,
}
console.log(msg);
sendgrid
     .send(msg)
     .then((resp) => {
         console.log('Email sent: \n', resp)
     })
     .catch((error) => {
         console.error(error)
 })
```

NOTE: *the message sent successfully and when I click the 3 dots the message shows then, but I want to shows it without let the user to do anything*

**How can I let my html email content in emails body appears as how other companies did without being hidden?**

Comment: Does that happen if you change the subject and `msgText`?

Comment: Yeah what philnash said--it looks like it's because of auto-threading based on the subject name (conversation view)

Comment: @philnash , the message send successfully and when i click the 3 dots the message shows then , but i want to shows it without let the user to do anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Gmails threading in action. It's because you already sent an e-mail with that subject and content, and Gmail is collapsing content which it thinks is old.

Try changing the content, and the subject, and try again. It should work just fine.

Either way, it's not a Sendgrid issue.

Comment: this was helpful and work well, thanks

Comment: Thanks @curly_brackets, I suspected it, glad you came up with the words for it!